# Android Error on Installation: [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY]

Tags: android, maven, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, emulation

So this has been bugging me for a while now. It used to work fine when I put it on an actual android device, and only showed the error when I tried to install my app on a emulator but now it is showing up on both the emulator and the actual device. The error is:

```
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.parse.starter
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY]
```

The logcat shows a lot of stuff but most of it looks like this (Uploading the entire logcat goes over my word limit):

> 04-25 21:23:25.420: ERROR/StrictMode(1703): null
>           android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection
>   com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cfecc0
>   that was originally bound here
>           at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.(LoadedApk.java:969)
>           at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
>           at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
>           at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
>           at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
>           at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
>           at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
>           at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
>           at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
>           at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
>           at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 04-25 21:23:25.447: ERROR/ActivityThread(1703): Service
>   com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection
>   com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cff068
>   that was originally bound here
>           android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection
>   com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cff068
>   that was originally bound here
>           at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.(LoadedApk.java:969)
>           at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
>           at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
>           at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
>           at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
>           at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
>           at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
>           at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
>           at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
>           at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
>           at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
>           at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

And finally, here is my manifest, anything wrong? I know it ussually has something to do with  but I think I have those in there already

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.parse.starter"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
    <permission
            android:name="com.parse.starter.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.parse.starter.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

    <application
        android:name="ParseApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ParseStarterProjectActivity"

            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Register"/>
        <activity android:name=".Login"/>
        <activity android:name=".MedicationInfo"/>
        <activity android:name=".Disclaimer"/>
        <activity android:name=".MainFragmentHolder"/>
        <activity android:name=".twitterShare"/>
        <receiver android:name=".AlarmManagerBroadcastReciever">
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".Notifications" >
        </service>

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
        <uses-library android:name="com.actionbarsherlock" />
        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="MY API KEY"/>
    </application>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.actionbarsherlock" />
```

as `<uses-library>` is only for firmware libraries.

Also, you appear to be using both Maps V1 and Maps V2, which is possible but unlikely. If you are trying to use Maps V2, get rid of:

```
 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
```

as that is Maps V1.

Comment: Thanks so much!! This worked perfectly :) Any way you can explain to me why? Or perhaps where I could find out more on why it worked?

Comment: @sourdesi: I though I did explain why. Android is an OS. It comes on devices. Those devices may have additional libraries that developers can opt into using, by means of `<uses-library>`. Maps V1 shipped as such a library, which is why you use `<uses-library>` for it. Maps V2 does not work this way, nor does any ordinary JAR or Android library project, which is why you do not use `<uses-library>` for Maps V2 or ActionBarSherlock.